# Ng Select - Prefill select multiple

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I´m trying to prefill [select multiple in angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2).

TS

```
  tipo:any;

  typeSelect: any = [
    { id: "1", descripcion: "Equipo" },
    { id: "2", descripcion: "Contadores" },
    { id: "3", descripcion: "Sensores" }
  ];

    this.tipo = 1;
```

HTML

```
  <ng-select [items]="typeSelect" name="tipo" bindLabel="descripcion" bindValue="id" placeholder="Tipo"
                [(ngModel)]="tipo" [multiple]="true" >
              </ng-select>
```

The problem: The select component does not show selected options. In this case as tipo==1, selected label should be 'Equipo' but doesn't show.

So any idea why can i fix this and show label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a multiple select dropdown so the `ngModel` will contain an array. Also, your `id` is a string and not a number.

Try this instead.

```js
this.tipo = ["1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to get data:

```
<ng-select2 [data]="exampleData"></ng-select2>
```